# GWT Injecting multiple scripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gwt, package, inject

I am trying to inject Javascript twice into my GWT app using ScriptInjector.fromURL().

The first inject works fine. As soon as I inject a second package, some of the CSS from the first package breaks/doesn't work. Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use ScriptInjector.fromURL() twice in your GWT app:

```js
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("first.js").setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(Void result) {
      // First script injection success
      // Load second script here
      ScriptInjector.fromUrl("second.js").setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            // Second script injection success
         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            // Second script injection failure
         }
      }).inject();
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Exception e) {
      // First script injection failure
   }
}).inject();
```

Make sure to wait for the first injected script to complete before starting the second one. You can use the Callback object to handle success and failure events for each injection.